# Typescript odd behaviour with looping over enum array

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum in typscript:

```
export enum MyEnum{
    value1,
    value2
}
```

And I have an array of enums:

```
let myEnumValues: Array<string | number> = [];
```

And I push an enum in:

```
myEnumValues.push(MyEnum.value2)
```

And if print the array:

```
console.log(myEnumValues);
// [ 1 ]
```

And if I loop through the array and print that:

```
for (var myEnumValue in myEnumValues) {
   console.log(myEnumValue);
   // 0
}
```

Why is it that I loop through an array that contains one item `1` and when I print it it's `0`?
I tried many variations and it is always different.

I can't figure it out.

Comment: for..in iterates over indexes, not values.

Comment: Oh!! how do I iterate over values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

`for (var myEnumValue of myEnumValues) {`

instead of

`for (var myEnumValue in myEnumValues) {`

Answer (score -1):

By default when using `enum` in TypeScript, it's a [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), meaning: The value for each key is a number that corresponds with the index of the key.

If you want string values, you'll have to define a string value per key:

```
export enum MyEnum{
    value1 = 'value1',
    value2 = 'value2'
}
```